# MFCC coeficient comparision

Tags: audio, speech-recognition

I have two sets of MFCC coeficients which I get with fftExtract utility from two wav audio files.

How can I compare this sets (matrix 271x13 and 551x13) if they are similar ?

Probably I should use EMD distance ...  But Im sligthly lost in all this math and I dont
know how to interpret its results .

How can I make from this distance matrix if both audio signals are similar or not - (Yes/Not)

I used following code for EMD :

```
function D = distEmd( X, Y )

Xcdf = cumsum(X,2);
Ycdf = cumsum(Y,2);

m = size(X,1);  n = size(Y,1);
mOnes = ones(1,m); D = zeros(m,n);
for i=1:n
  ycdf = Ycdf(i,:);
  ycdfRep = ycdf( mOnes, : );
  D(:,i) = sum(abs(Xcdf - ycdfRep),2);
end
```

### fftExtract

http://digitalmusics.dartmouth.edu/wiki/index.php/Music103_Tutorial

Comment: any specific reason you are using earth mover's distance? Wiki says it is used to find distance between probability distributions. I don't think MFCCs are prob. distributions. Perhaps you could use  Dynamic Time Warping method to find distances.

Comment: Well I have read some articles where people used it with MFCCs so I wanted to try it . I think EMD is faster than DTW.    [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/DSP/comments/17hyr5/how_is_it_possible_to_compare_two_audio_signals/)

Comment: I don't think EMD is a good idea for audio signals, faster it may be, but its idea is to compare distributions/histograms. Anyway, if you *want* to use it then create a 50 bin histograms from your data. Now both matrices will be of size 50x13.